# Use a view's column alias in a seperate SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, alias

I created a view that has one column with an alias, and now I want to use the MAX() function on this column from a seperate SELECT statement, but I don't know how. (I keep getting the "invalid identifier" error for what I write in the MAX() function.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW C17_AbfrageBView AS
SELECT p.PersonID, p.Vorname, p.Nachname,
       COUNT(DISTINCT f.FachID) "Fachanzahl" -- this column
FROM  ...
GROUP BY p.PersonID, p.Vorname, p.Nachname
ORDER BY 4;


SELECT PersonID, Vorname, Nachname,
       MAX(Fachanzahl) "Fachanzahl" -- right here
FROM C17_AbfrageBView
GROUP BY PersonID, Vorname, Nachname;
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT ..., MAX(COUNT(DISTINCT FachID)) "Fachanzahl"
FROM C17_AbfrageBView
...
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't know why you get that error, but in the view you are already grouping over those columns, why do you do it again in the select? The `MAX` you are trying to select will be identical to the value in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view C17_AbfrageBView has a column named `"Fachanzahl"` (case-sensitive, double-quotes required), so you must refer to that when querying the view.

You can describe the view (`describe c17_abfragebview` in SQL*Plus, or right-click on the name in your IDE) to confirm the list of available columns.

Case-sensitive names are inconvenient though, so I would strongly advise naming the column `Fachanzahl` and not `"Fachanzahl"`.

Answer (score -1):

you just must use as below

```
SELECT PersonID, Vorname, Nachname,
       MAX([Fachanzahl]) "Fachanzahl" -- right here
FROM C17_AbfrageBView
GROUP BY PersonID, Vorname, Nachname;
```

using `[]`

regards.